# gradle exclude transitive dependency issue

Tags: gradle

I am trying to exclude a transitive dependency like below

```
compile('org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.6.1'){
        exclude group:'org.apache.hadoop' , module :'hadoop-client'
}
```

When I try to print the dependencies using "gradle dependencies --configuration compile" this dependency still shows up.

I have verified and this dependency is not mentioned in any other place in the build.gradle

Comment: is org.apache.spark:spark-core mentioned anywhere else?

Comment: [note that](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) "Not every transitive dependency can be excluded - some transitive dependencies might be essential for correct runtime behavior of the application"

Comment: Yes the issue was "org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10" was a transitive dependency for "org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.10".   Resolve the issue by defining it at configuration level                                 configurations {

 all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'hadoop-client'
}